# Accepted answer ,up vote and bounty award

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer, up-votes

Recently I posted a question on Pro WebMasters. After a couple of days no one had answered my question so I decided to start a bounty. After a while someone actually gave me a solution, so I accepted his answer. I waited until I could award him with the bounty and since I was capable of up vote him, I did that also. Isn't accepting an answer implies that you like his answer and you also want to reward him?

Comment: 15 for the acceptance.

Comment: @AndrewC Thanx I wish I could both up vote and accept you comment!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you concerned that that +15 for accept and +10 for up-voting are also being subtracted from you reputation? They're not, only the +50 bounty that you already paid for. Upvoting and accepting just gives them more reputation without costing you any.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most people do this. If you got a great answer from your bounty, why _wouldn't_ you upvote and accept it as well?

Comment: Why shouldn't they get all the rep for a good answer?

Comment: Don't get me wrong,I do think that he should get all the reputation I can offer to him,after all I've already done it. And I know reputation isn't subtracted from mine. I think it's not beneficial. Why then I shouldn't upvote him twice or even accept more than one answer?

Comment: Because you can't upvote twice, nor accept more than one answer.

Comment: @AndrewC But I can up vote him accept him and reward him at the same time.That make more sense.

Comment: If you're worried about someone getting to much rep from this, there is a rep cap (200 rep, but bounties and accepts don't count towards it).

Comment: No this is not my worry.

Comment: BTW, the SE system still works with 500K+ rep (see Jon Skeet). We don't know when his rep will overflow the var, but removing upvote rep and accept rep from bountied answers isn't going to put a big dent in his income.

Comment: What is your worry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that it is against the rules to accept and upvote a good answer on top of the bounty.  As far as I can tell, the 50 rep is from you, the 25 (acceptance + upvote) is given by SE on your behalf in recognition of a good and helpful answer.

I have done this also, I felt the answer was very helpful and happily upvoted, accepted the answer and gave the bounty.

Having said all that, if I am mistaken, can someone please correct me.